# SQL Client on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile

I'm developing on Android and currently haev various methods which manage my database in a convenient class.

What I'd ideally like, though, is a (preferably GUI) sql client that would allow me to view the contents of a different apps' DB.

Eg:

I install my own app (App1). It creates and uses a DB
I install 
I use SQLClient to examine App1's DB.

Does anyone know if anything like this exists? If not, I can see a way that it could be implemented assuming I can get permission (and a naming convention) for accessing another apps' DB.

Any ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated.

As an alternative, I'd be willing to run something on the PC while the phone is connected via USB (I know there's a tool that comes with the android SDK but it's a little clunky and as I mentioned, a GUI would be preferable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this for development - you can install new [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/) from Motorola (it's free) It has UI for SQlite

Comment: Fantastic - This looks like exactly what I was after - Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the SQLite database on the scdcard you could use:
http://aaa.andsen.dk/aSQLiteManager.html
A free open source SQLite Manager for Android

Answer (score 1):

See [Using SQLite from Shell in Android](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/using-sqlite-from-shell-in-android.aspx)

but that's not a GUI, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such application.

The only way to access another Application's database is through a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). So a "native" SQL client won't be possible. You have to deal with the access that the target application provides. If it doesn't offer a ContentProvider, then you're stuck with the SDK's solution.

Another option would be to - as you mentioned - write an application on the PC. You could use this in tandem with an application on Android with opens up a [`ServerSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and forwards incoming commands directly to SQLite. Essentially writing an SQLite Proxy :) **This is very "hackish", SQL-Injectable and otherwise attackable**. In a controlled debug/test environment this shouldn't be an issue though.

This just popped into my mind. There may be other solutions...

Comment: Thanks very much - the info on ContentProvider was very useful (Haven't reached it in the docs yet and it answers some questions).

The ideal of proxying is also great - It gives me a starting point for something a bit more robust & secure.

If I get a good solution, I'll post details.